# Heroku application log streaming

Tags: api, curl, heroku

I'm trying to use the new Heroku api to stream the logs of my application using curl:
Here is what is said in the doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#app)

```
Streaming is performed by doing an HTTP GET method on the provided logplex url and retrieving log lines utilizing chunked encoding.
```

So first I retrieve the logplex url:

```
curl -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/my-app/log-sessions \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" \
-H "Authorization:XXX" -v
```

Then I get something like this in the response:

```
"logplex_url":"https://logplex.heroku.com/sessions/abcdef-079b-4264-a83c-031feb31bfc2?srv=132456798"
```

So I make another curl call:

```
curl -X GET "https://logplex.heroku.com/sessions/abcdef-8a7e-442f-a164-4c64e845b62d?srv=123456798" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
```

I got a persistent connection but nothing comes...

If I don't specify the Transfer-Encoding header, I get the logs,  but the connection close.

Is it really possible to stream the logs, like it's specified in the reference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, unfortunately I was mistaken in writing it and it is not chunked encoding as I believed. We do use this interface in the CLI and in log2viz, but it is unfortunately not standard http per se.

Basically you should do a normal HTTP request and read back the HTTP response headers. Given the headers returned you would then normally read from the socket until you got a zero length read, at which point you can assume you are done and finish up. In the logplex case we are reticent to block (perhaps indefinitely) so we go ahead and return an empty read. Then we just expect that when you are done you can simply close the socket.

Unfortunately I was unable to figure out how to do this with cURL. But I can point to the examples in our open source where we tackle this, and hopefully that will help.

- toolbelt - https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client.rb#L482
- log2viz - https://github.com/heroku/log2viz/blob/master/app.rb#L153

Hopefully that helps clarify the current situation at least, I'll try to update the docs to reflect this. Thanks for the detailed report and let me know if you have additional questions I can help with.

Comment: Additionally, depending on your use case you might be better served using log drains. But we haven't yet had a chance to add those to the new public API. You can see how to use them here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog-drains